# Saving/Exporting an Image (Directly from 3D View)

Tags: rendering, image, saving

What if I want to save an image, but not actually render it?

An ‘unrendered’ image.

It’s important to note (I think) that the window captured in the screenshot *was* the UV Editor, containing the rendered image—as well as the option to ‘Save As Image’ (F3)—right up until I selected ‘3D View’ from the popup menu at lower-left.

Now that I’ve selected that, and have the image I want, there is no option to save or export it.

Please help.[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your only options are to either do an *OpenGL Render* (available via the Render menu at the top of the window) - which will re-render your image using OpenGL (which is what the viewport uses so is quick and should look the same as your image) - or you can tell Blender to take a *screenshot* of your current Blender window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> (although once you've saved your screenshot you'll need to open an image editor (eg, Gimp) to trim off the rest of the window as the screenshot will consist of everything).